# Forward DNS queries of a subdomain to another port

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, forwarding

I have some software which provides dynamic information via DNS, similar to a DNSBL.

How do I run it on the same server as a BIND server that's also serving DNS requests for other domains? I just need BIND to redirect queries to a certain subdomain (*.myservice.myname.net) to a different port on the same machine, and I can't just delegate the subdomain because I don't have an IPv4 address to spare.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, this is **impossible**. It's as if the BIND authors have explicitly went out of their way to make sure no one can accomplish this - at least, not without making your server an open resolver.

- Unlike some other DNS software, BIND does not support a "forward" record type (which would simply make the software consult a different server when matched). There is no way to add forwarding at the "zone" level.
- Although it's possible to create a forwarding (`type forward`) zone for a subdomain, which also allows querying a DNS server on an arbitrary port, for some reason this requires enabling the `allow-recursion` option to work.
- However, the `allow-recursion` option cannot be specified at the zone level - it can either be a global option (and enabling it there opens your server's DNS up as a public resolver), or in a "view".
- Views allow grouping zones and applying certain options (including `allow-recursion`) to them, however, since their purpose is to restrict by client/server IPs, they will also not behave as one might expect and match even zones that are not explicitly specified in them (thus making your server a public resolver).
- BIND does have a way to restrict queries to only those zones explicitly listed in a view: a blank `allow-query` at the `view` level, and `allow-query { any; };` at the zone level. Unfortunately: `option 'allow-query' is not allowed in 'forward' zone`. That's the verbatim message BIND gives you.